# python pylibmc not installing

Tags: python, windows

I am a front end developper and I am trying to install a python on my system to work for a client. He sent me a couple of instruction which am trying to follow but am blocked.

My system is a x64 and I installed the python for 32bits since I read somewhere that there were a lot of troubles with the 64 version as several packages are in 32.

here is a couple of lines of the error I have :

```
s-oauthlib>=0.3.0->django-allauth==0.18.0->-r requirements\base.txt (line 23))
Installing collected packages: pylibmc
Running setup.py install for pylibmc
building '_pylibmc' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DUSE_ZLIB -I
C:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /Tcsrc/_pylibmcmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src/_pylibmcmodule.obj
-fno-strict-aliasing
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fno-strict-aliasing'
_pylibmcmodule.c
c:\users\iknsa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-dj2nd12i\pylibmc\src\_pylibmcmodule.h(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot op
en include file: 'libmemcached/memcached.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\iknsa\\AppD
ata\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-dj2nd12i\\pylibmc\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().r
eplace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\iknsa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-f29lv3f2-record\install
-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
```

which the ends with these lines :

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DUSE_ZLIB -I
C:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /Tcsrc/_pylibmcmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src/_pylibmcmodule.obj
 -fno-strict-aliasing

    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fno-strict-aliasing'

    _pylibmcmodule.c

    c:\users\iknsa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-dj2nd12i\pylibmc\src\_pylibmcmodule.h(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot op
en include file: 'libmemcached/memcached.h': No such file or directory

    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Any help would be most welcome

Comment: doesn't look like pylibmc has been ported to windows...

Comment: This *should* work on windows. Lets see if I can do anything.

Comment: This definitely does not work since there is a dependency on libmemcached which is not installable on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the most recent version of libmemcached from its [Launchpad download page](https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/+download).

With this, make sure that all headers are available from the include search path, which in your case would be `C:\Python34\include` (as hinted by the output); you could also place them in the search path of your compiler (which for MinGW's gcc would be something like `mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.3.0\include`).

One issue I ran into while trying to do the same was that by default, it builds with SASL support, and doing that on Windows [seems to be tricky](https://github.com/toddlipcon/python-sasl/issues/3). You can build libmemcached without SASL support by changing `libmemcached\configure.h:45` to `#define LIBMEMCACHED_WITH_SASL_SUPPORT 0` (as of version 1.0.18).